# How can I use not own swf file in my website?

Tags: flash

I want use swf file in my website, but i dont know how.

The problem is that this is not a simple swf (example: [swf file, what i want to use](http://open-beta.seafight.com/client/res/ships/ship_639.swf)). When I open it in a flash player, then nothing happens, only white screen, and even if you add it on the Web page.

Somebody can help me? :) How can I use this swf?

Comment: Obviously you cant. It's their content and most likely is coded to work from their server address only. Also it might need to access other files from that server which you have not copied across, one SWF file is not everything!! Did you get the JPEGs? The PNGs? the MP3s? any videos? etc etc... Next!!

Comment: Thank you! If I download these swf files, i can decompile with decompiler, and I can use the pictures from swf. Can I make this on webpage, online? Automatically decompile the swf and show the images?